# What is the reccommended pattern for re-using a data contract as an object model in code?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I own a service and publish a contract like

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Foo { get; }

    public string Bar { set; }
}
```

I imagine that it is not proper have "behavior" in a data contract, things like

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Foo { get; }

    public string Bar { set; }

    public void DoSomeAlgorithmWithMyProperties() { … }
}
```

In other words, data contracts are supposed to be just value bags.

So my question is how I create behavior on a such an object. One way I can see is to just create a separate mirroring object, like

```
public class MyObjectInternal
{
    public int Foo { get; }

    public string Bar { set; }

    public class MyObjectInternal(int foo, string bar)
    {
        this.Foo = foo;
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public void DoSomeAlgorithmWithMyProperties() { … }
}
```

Another is inheritance

```
public class MyObjectInternal : MyObject
{
    public class MyObjectInternal(int foo, string bar)
    {
        this.Foo = foo;
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public void DoSomeAlgorithmWithMyProperties() { … }
}
```

and other possibility could be to just completely separate out behavior and data by having separate classes that operation on the values, like

```
public static class MyObjectAlgorithmDoer
{
     public static void DoSomeAlgorithmWithMyProperties(MyObject myObject) { … }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are two ways you can add behaviour to your `MyObject` contract. One way is to create a service which talks to `MyObject` like this:

```
public class MyObjectService 
{
    public void DoOperation(MyObject myObject) 
    {
    }
}
```

`MyObjectService` class then can be called by your application to perform the operation.

In the above approach what you have is an anemic domain model where you keep data and operations upon this data separate from each other. The issue with this approach is that it can lead to code duplication and it can lead of violations of data integrity. Still, this can be a good approach if your application is simple.

If however, your system is complex and evolving, then you can look to follow [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). From wiki:

> The premise of domain-driven design is the following:
>
> - placing the project's primary focus on the core domain and domain logic;
> - basing complex designs on a model of the domain;
> - initiating a creative collaboration between technical and domain experts to iteratively refine a conceptual model that addresses
>     particular domain problems.

DDD can be hard to follow initially. I would suggest you to understand the concept completely before jumping to the solution. Here are some good references and tutorials to understand DDD

- https://airbrake.io/blog/software-design/domain-driven-design
- Pluralsight course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/refactoring-anemic-domain-model

Answer (score 0):

In your case using inheritance is not a right approach. I can not understand why you think inheritance might help you? in your case using inheritance is tight coupling and also breaks in encapsulation(if you have more than one subclass) also same for abstract class. I think you might need [Domain model pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335249/domain-model-pattern-example) and define proper value objects. I do recommend you read [patterns of enterprise application](https://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) book, in this book introduce different pattern to create your domain model.